# Keep changes while doing a `git stash`

Tags: git

Is there any way that I can run `git stash` have it create a stash of my files, but also keep them around so that I can continue editing them.

My motivation for this is that I would like to create a temporary snapshot of some work I'm doing, so that I can go back to it if I muck things up. However, my code is not currently in a state where I want to actually commit it, and if my test works as I expected, I want to throw the old version away without it ever being in my history.

Obviously I can just make a copy the directory my repo is in, and work in one of them, but is there a better way?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to fake a commit. Why are you trying to fake a commit as opposed to just doing one?

Comment: @BradMace What if he wants to make backups, but does not want to clutter his commit history with meaningless commits?

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss I wasn't intending to say he was wrong, just trying to understand what his goal was. (I think he edited in some more info during the 5-minute edit window). My suggestion in this case would be to do the commits, and then squash them afterward, before pushing to the main repo.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is (as far as I am aware) not a way to do this with `git stash` with one command, but you can do it with two uses of `git stash`.

The commands you want to run are:

```
git stash
git stash apply
```

The first one takes your local changes and pushes them to the stash, thus removing them from HEAD. The second one takes the changes from the stack, and puts them back in HEAD, but also leaves a copy of them on your stash stack.

Comment: You could make a git alias to do this in a single command by doing `git stash save` immediately followed by `git stash apply`.

Answer (score 6):

I think a better solution in this situation is to create a topic branch.

In Git, branches are very cheap.

If you have work that you want to "stash" away to come back to later do this:

```
git checkout -b myStashBranch
git add .
git commit -m "savepoint when I foo..."
```

then, simply switch back to the branch you were currently on:

```
git checkout -
```

and continue on with the task at hand...

If you get to a point where you want to simply throw away that "stashed" work that you just saved do:

```
git branch -D myStashBranch
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you're worried about "broken commits" (that is, commits where the code doesn't compile, or isn't fully functional), you can always squash or reorder commits before merging back into `master`, or while rebasing onto `master`.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

```
git stash store -m "WIP on $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD): $(git log -1 --format="%h %s")" $(git stash create)
```

or

```
git add -A; git stash --keep-index
```

There pros/cons to both. The first does not mess around with the state of your working directory at all, but is quite verbose (although turning it into an alias will mitigate this). The second one is simpler, but means that all your changes will be staged (this may or may not be desired).

The benefit of these over

```
git stash
git stash apply
```

is that the all the files will need to be modified twice. This can cause issues with speed if there are number of files, or if you are using an IDE that might attempt to rebuild after every time a file changes. If this is is not an issue than by all means use it.

It would have been nice of Git to provide

```
git stash --keep-working-dir
```

If you are going to do these with any regularity than you should make an alias.

Answer (score 1):

For the type of workflow you are talking about, I would say it is better to create a temporary topic branch to work in.

```
git checkout -b couldgowrong
```

If you like your changes when you are done, then simply `rebase` your topic branch onto your `master` branch and delete the branch; the `rebase` will keep your history clean (i.e. no dual parent merge).

```
git rebase master couldgowrong
git checkout master
git branch -D couldgowrong
```

If you don't like your changes, then simply skip the `rebase` and delete the topic branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it saved me,

If use in **"JetBrains"** IDE (IntelliJ, PyCharm etc.),

Click right click on main parent folder of the project and choose "Local History" and then "Show History":

[image]

Now can see on the new window in the right side all the files that have always been in the project according to the times on the left, and of course make them revert or see differences.